# Multi axis bubble chart

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a bubble chart for a product positioning map
On the x axis is price, and size of the bubble is the sales volume.
On the Y axis - It has be multi-level with upto 5 attributes - discrete.
The chart has to be dynamic as the attributes can be resequenced or deleted, i.e., any number of attributes can be selected.
Something like:

[image: Product positioning map]

Comment: It would be useful to see the data that would correspond to this chart. Also, what have you tried and what problem did you encounter?